# How to color individual elements in matplotlib plot_trisurf

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a triangular surface mesh, generated via marching cubes. I want to color the surface elements based on an arbitrary variable in my plot. I am currently using plot_trisurf, but as I read the documentation, it looks like the color is always based on the Z component, or else a constant? Can I not specify a color per element? Or is there a better plot routine to use? For example, something along the lines of the code below is what I am after, where the color is based on the 'value' output from the marching cubes. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import measure
from skimage.draw import ellipsoid

from matplotlib import cm


# Generate a level set about zero of two identical ellipsoids in 3D
ellip_base = ellipsoid(6, 10, 16, levelset=True)
# Use marching cubes to obtain the surface mesh of these ellipsoids
verts, faces, normals, values = measure.marching_cubes_lewiner(ellip_double, 0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_trisurf(verts[:, 0], verts[:,1], verts[:, 2], triangles=faces, cmap=cm.rainbow, color=values)

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")

ax.set_xlim(0, 24)  
ax.set_ylim(0, 20) 
ax.set_zlim(0, 32)  

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe  [plot_trisurface with custom color array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298864/plot-trisurface-with-custom-color-array) is relevant here? That seems to hint at `ax.plot_trisurf(...., facecolors=cmap(norm(values)))`. Also note that matplotlib only has limited 3D capabilities. You might want to look at e.g. Mayavi.

Comment: Digging around in there, they don't specify color in the command, but you can apparently set it after the fact. I'll post as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by JohanC, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298864/plot-trisurface-with-custom-color-array) they reset the face colors after the fact. This works for me, as I already have an array of colors defined.

```
# set the face colors of the Poly3DCollection
p3dc.set_fc(colors)
```